# Magento 2 when deploying code cache generation 7 steps

Tags: magento2, cache

I have one question regarding deploy code generation using command line

`php/bin magento setup:di:compile`

we always seen below line

> Compilation was started. Interception cache generation... 7/7
>   [============================] 100% 1 min 264.0 MiB Generated code and
>   dependency injection configuration successfully.

I am not understanding **what are 7 steps(7/7 ) when cache generation**.

Have anybody idea about these 7 steps?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html

Answer (score 0):

Code compilation consists of all of the following 7 Steps(in no particular order):

```
Application code generation (factories, proxies, and so on)
Area configuration aggregation (that is, optimized dependency injection configurations per area)
Interceptor generation (that is, optimized code generation of interceptors)</li>
Interception cache generation
Proxies code generation
Repositories code generation (that is, generated code for APIs)
Service data attributes generation (that is, generated extension classes for data objects)
```

Know more : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html